# Line of Tag information Is Formatted Strange

Tags: tags

I'm placing a tag list in the post footers on a blog.

You can go to this specific post: http://www.smallfryblog.com/2013/09/03/small-fry-films-midtown/ and scroll down to the post footer see what the tags looks like currently:

"filmsvideoTags:," is what it looks like to me.

I would like it to look like "Tags: films, videos"

Here's my code:

```
<?php the_tags('Tags:', ', ', '<br/>'); ?>
```

which is according to the codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

I've tried all different kinds of things trying to figure out what the problem is...with no solution found yet. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of some CSS that you have.

This is what causes your problem, the float:left

```
utility a {
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

Add the code that generates your tags in a div with "float: none"

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't build this site, I'm just adding this in for them, so I couldn't figure out what was going on. I thought it might be a CSS problem, but couldn't see what it was. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that worked. If you're pleased with my answer, please vote it or accept it :)

Comment: Definitely – won't let me accept it for another 4 mintues, but I will